# automate the loadui

Tags: scripting, automated-tests, loadui

I am using Windows OS. I went through the loadui website to understand the automation process. As I am very new with this software, I cant even understand how to run certain command. For example, there is command like this "loadUI-Agent-1_5_0.exe -c" need to be run in command line.

I try to paste it in command prompt, but it is not recognized. Anybody have any idea how to do that? It is very good if you guys can provide me link to learn from zero, where I can follow step by step to automate the load testing using loadui.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `loadui-cmd.bat`, which can be found in the LoadUI installation directory.

You should also use the latest version of LoadUI which is 2.1.1.

Source: [Getting Started with Automation](http://loadui.org/Load-Test-Automation/load-test-automation-getting-started.html) from the LoadUI documentation.